# Integration testing an asp.net Web Api Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

I'm currently working on a project that uses a form based UI which calls a Rest API in the backend. The UI is developed using HTML/JQuery/JavaScript and backend is developed using ASP.NET Web API. We are planning to write an End to End tests that simulates user actions and verifies the returned response, which will be in a json format.

**Question:**

I wanted to know what kind of frameworks/techniques are available that makes such integration testing easy(JavaScript-> WebApi). Also, if any one has done something similar and can share their experience?

**My Research**

While doing some research online, I came across the following frameworks. However, I havent worked with either of them, so am not aware of their pros and cons. I am planning on writing simple tests and evaluate their features

```
Jasmin (http://jasmine.github.io/)  (JavaScript based framework)
Cucumber (http://www.specflow.org/) (BDD based framework)
```

Answer (score 1):

Chander, as you are looking at end to end testing, could you not simply do CodedUI tests in Visual Studio.  We currently do this for a similar architecture to you.  They can be written by non-coders using the wizard and are very straightforward.  Not to mention integrated into the Microsoft Stack so the experience for the tester in identifying why its gone wrong is much better.

Comment: Let me give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I would like to mention a framework called [RestFluencing](http://1) that is trying to resolve exactly API integration testing.

```
Rest.GetFromUrl("https://api.github.com/users/defunkt")
    .WithHeader("User-Agent", "RestFluencing Sample")
    .Response()
    .ReturnsDynamic(c => c.login == "defunkt", "Login did not match")
    .ReturnsDynamic(c => c.id == 2, "ID did not match") 
    .Assert();
```

Also if you have a class model you could use an JsonSchema validator:

```
public class GitHubUser
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string login { get; set; }
}
```

Validating:

```
Rest.GetFromUrl("https://api.github.com/users/defunkt")
    .Response()
    .HasJsonSchema<GitHubUser>(new JSchemaGenerator())
    .Assert();
```

Check out the GitHub page: [RestFluencing](https://github.com/djmnz/RestFluencing)

Disclaimer: I am the dev for that framework. Doing an full integration api testing in an easy way in C# has been something that I have been looking for a long time, hence this Fluent-style framework.